# Concatenate two commands with output on sam line Ansible shell command

Tags: bash, ansible

I have this ansible command that is writing Docker container ip address and hostname to nginx hosts file which is running for more than 1 time.

How can I join two commands and get ouput on same line and also write the ouput on end of file?

shell:

```
echo -n docker inspect --format '{''{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }''}' hq1; echo abc.com >> ../templates/hosts.j2
```

Output should look like this:

```
172.2.3.1 hq1.abc.com
172.2.3.2 hq2.abc.com
```

Comment: You write that you want "output on same line", yet your desired output has two lines.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to append the string `abc.com` to the end of each line of output from some command.

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' hq1 |
sed 's/$/abc.com/' >>../templates/hosts.j2
```

The `sed` command simply replaces the end of the line with the string `abc.com`.